# Setting up call enqueueing and forwarding using Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, ivr, twilio-studio

I was recently trying to use the Twilio Studio to set up an IVR system to route the calls to the correct numbers based on the selected user input. I was able to create the following workflow and it works fine.
[image: Current Workflow]
Here I am able to split the call based on user's input via keypad or voice and direct the call to the corresponding number. I am also able to track the number of times a user has pressed an invalid input and disconnect the call after a specific number of invalid inputs. It's all working fine.

Now I am trying to enqueue the calls so that users will stay in a queue while the agent is busy. I also want to forward the calls to a specif number and if that number does not pick or reject, call another number. This helps me to make sure that the calls are not missed. I also added a call forwarding option with recording enabled. But when I try to play the recording, it says an application error occurred.

I have been trying to contact support regarding the documentation or examples fo the above requirements, but it's very hard to get a reply as I don't have paid support enabled. Can anyone suggest good documentation with an example to handle my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For queueing calls and then having more than one number called you should take a look at [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/how-taskrouter-works). It turns calls into tasks that can be assigned to workers via a workflow and can definitely handle your need to dial more than one person. You can then send your call into the workflow from Studio using the [enqueue widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#enqueue-call).

As for your recording issue, can you provide more detail? How did you add the call forwarding with recording option? How did you try to play the recording? Was there any more detail in the [Twilio Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger)?

Comment: I already have a task router and have added workers to that. Also when I try to play the recording it says an application error has occurred. If you want I can share more logs that I got from the debug

Comment: More logs would definitely help me figure out what’s going on.